# An error occurs when I try to login my application in my local env, with Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a new of laravel and trying to setup my first application.
An error occurs when I try to login my application as below.
Could someone advise me how to resolve this?

Similar consultation in other lines however these are not resolved or seem not to suit my case.

#### Error description

```
TypeError
Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, App\Models\user given, called in /home/vagrant/code/projectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php on line 415
```

#### App/Model/user.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class user extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

      /**
     * Get the name of the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'id';
    }

       /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

      /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

       /**
     * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->rememberToken;
    }

        /**
     * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

        /**
     * Get the column name for the "remember me" token.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
}
```

#### Database/Migrate/create_users_table.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

#### app/Http/Auth/Controllers/LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{ 
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    // use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    // public function __construct()
    // {
    //     $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    // }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'メールアドレスまたはパスワードが正しくありません。',
        ]);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Comment: @soroushganjooe Thank you for correcting my code, my code has been modified and it has worked!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your user class should extend Authenticatable :

```
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
 {



 }
```

Comment: `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` is an interface so the class should have `implements Authenticatable` however in the [boilerplate Laravel source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Models/User.php) it has `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;` in which case `extends Authenticatable` would be correct

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for explanation of interface in laravel, however I could not understand how to use it. Will reserach more :)